# Can a thrown weapon be picked up?

Tags: dnd-4e, improvised-weaponry, ranged-attack

I was creating a Paladin recently and came across a conundrum...save for a Daily power, he has no ranged abilities, meaning I can't engage a creature I cannot reach by the end of my turn.

So my question is...is it possible to PICK UP a javelin, throwing hammer/axe/dagger, etc. after it has been used? And do I need to "buy" multiple javelins, etc. to use more than one per encounter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. You automatically collect any thrown weapons after the encounter. You will probably want several of them just to make sure you can use them. I play a couple of heavy melee chars and they both carry about 5 javelins and have never run out.

Of interest, if you pick up a magic javelin you will only need one. Magic thrown weapons return after they are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pick up a thrown weapon within the encounter.  The DM needs to decide how to determine its location.  I don't believe there are existing rules for this, but it's pretty simple to make one up.  If the attack was a hit, either the weapon is lodged in the target or not -- probably not.  If it was a miss, or the weapon struck and fell, roll 1d8 to determine its location:

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | T | 5 |
+---+---+---+
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+
```

(T is the target.)

You can pick up a weapon from your square or a nearby square as a minor action.  (PHB p289)  You should carefully consider whether you want your character to have to close on the thrown weapon and pick it up before making another attack.